# SCEP Payload Not working

Tags: java, certificate, profile, payload, csr

I've sent a device a configuration profile with an SCEP payload. When the device downloads this config profile, it is supposed to connect to my Java SCEP server and write a CSR to its OutputStream in PKCS10 form. However, when I print the contents of the stream, I get a bunch of garbled nonsense; I know that the request should start with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- and end with -----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----, but this is not the case. Here is the SCEP payload:

```
            <dict>
                    <key>PayloadContent</key>
                    <dict>
                            <key>Key Type</key>
                            <string>RSA</string>
                            <key>Key Usage</key>
                            <integer>0</integer>
                            <key>Keysize</key>
                            <integer>1024</integer>
                            <key>Name</key>
                            <string>CA-SCEP</string>
                            <key>Subject</key>
                            <array/>
                            <key>URL</key>
                            <string>https://myserver.example.com </string>
                    </dict>
                    <key>PayloadDescription</key>
                    <string>Configures SCEP</string>
                    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
                    <string>SCEP (CA-SCEP)</string>
                    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
                    <string>com.Example.rdesirazu.SCEP</string>
                    <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
                    <string>Example</string>
                    <key>PayloadType</key>
                    <string>com.apple.security.scep</string>
                    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
                    <string>5C125B3C-4427-49CE-980B-21FC1254D506</string>
                    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
                    <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you will never get anything close to what you expect with SCEP. These are your best friends:

- http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/public-key-infrastructure-pki/116167-technote-scep-00.html
- https://github.com/jscep/jscep/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jscep/server/ScepServlet.java